# Binding in php with postgres

Tags: php, postgresql

I have problem with bindings, I want to insert name or surname in label Pisatelj as keyword to search for this author, 
I want also do the same way if I insert keyword for Naslov(=Title of book)
please correct my code 
I have this code in php with postgres:

```
function get_knjige_sql ( )
{
    global $CRUD;
    $dbh = $CRUD['dbh'];
        $str_query = '';
        if(isset($_POST['Knaslov'])){
                $str_query = addslashes($_POST['Knaslov']);
        }
        if(isset($_POST['Ppriimek'])){
                $str_query = addslashes($_POST['Ppriimek']);
        } 

    $query = " SELECT *  FROM knjiga, pisatelj, zaloga WHERE (knjiga.naslov ILIKE '?' OR CONCAT(pisatelj.ime, ' ', pisatelj.priimek) ILIKE '?' ) AND knjiga.p_id = pisatelj.p_id AND knjiga.k_id = zaloga.k_id AND zaloga.prodana = false ";
    if($sth)
    $sth->bindValue(':Knaslov', $Knaslov, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sth->bindValue(':Ppriimek', $Ppriimek, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    if($sth)
    $sth->execute();

    else error('get_knjige_sql: select prepare returned no statement handle');

    $err = $sth->errorInfo();
    if($err[0] != 0) error( $err[2] );

    return($sth);
}
```

#### main.php:

```
<!-- main html file for CRUD (php version) -->
<?php echo $CRUD["MESSAGES"] ?><?php echo $CRUD["ERRORS"] ?>
<div class="form">
<form action="<?php echo $CRUD["SELF"] ?>" method="post" name="knjiga">
    <p class="subheading"><?php echo $CRUD["FORM_HEAD"] ?></p>

    <table class="form">
    <tr>
        <td><p class="Afield"> Naslov:</p></td>
        <td><input class="Afield" type="text" name="Knaslov" value="<?php echo $CRUD["Knaslov"] ?>"> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><p class="Afield"> Isbn:</p></td>
        <td><input class="Afield" type="text" name="kisbn" value="<?php echo $CRUD["Kisbn"] ?>"> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><p class="Afield"> Cena:</p></td>
        <td><input class="Afield" type="text" name="Kcena" value="<?php echo $CRUD["Kcena"] ?>"> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><p class="Afield"> Pisatelj:</p></td>
        <td><input class="Afield" type="text" name="Ppriimek" value="<?php echo $CRUD["Pime"] ?><?php echo $CRUD["Ppriimek"] ?>"> </td>

    </tr>

    <tr class="buttons"><td colspan="2">
<p class="buttons">
<?php echo $CRUD["BUTTONS"] ?><?php echo $CRUD["HIDDENS"] ?>
</p>
    </td></tr>
    </table>


</form>
</div>
<?php echo $CRUD["PRECONTENT"] ?><?php echo $CRUD["CONTENT"] ?><?php echo $CRUD["POSTCONTENT"] ?>
```

Comment: I want to post code here, but I cannot, I tried with ctrl+k and insert code in the midle of `code here` but it doesnt work, so I post to pastebin.com

Comment: Don't paste it into "code here", just paste in the code, highlight it, then ctl-k

Comment: Your query itself is not using the placeholders that you are using in the bindValue()

Comment: Lots is confusing here.  What is `$sth`? That isn't in scope in this function. Did you mean `$dbh`? Looks like you are trying to use PDO. You never called `$dbh->prepare()` before binding values and executing. Finally, you should not quote the `?` placeholders as `'?'` in the prepared statement. Since you bound named parameters, those should appear in your prepared statement instead of `?` as in `knjiga.naslov ILIKE :knaslov`

Comment: Finally, remove both `addslashes()`. That is not needed when binding parameters (and is the wrong way to escape, even when not using prepared statements)

Comment: This is the full code: http://pastebin.com/5iQ2rfC1 and there is this code to change to my code: http://pastebin.com/c0q3xMW9

Comment: Now my function get_knjige_sql() works if I insert in a label Naslov(=means Title of book) any keyword, I want that will do the same if I insert author name or surname, or both together with space between them in other label Pisatelj(=means Author of book), here is my code: http://pastebin.com/xAS8XvEd  and  http://pastebin.com/DBcC1uRY